# volatile variable error in Chrome's JS engine?

Tags: javascript, v8

According to my understanding, in JS there are not race conditions for synchronous code. That is, during the execution of a function variables should only be accessed by 1 executing thread.

However, I have run across this:
[image]

In this image you can observe how the predicate of the if statement in line 186 evaluates to true. The code inside the if statement contains only a return statement. Hence, there is no way the thread could have escaped the if statement.

Some context into what sort of functions are calling into this:

This is a service worker MV3 extension.

A number of function stacks are awaiting for the closePromise. Once the close promise resolves, my premise is that the first "thread" to call __innitialize will pass the if statements into the executing thread. When the next "thread" calls __initialize, then the first one would have changed the state to INITIALIZING, thus he would enter the first if statement, and await for the initPromise.

I may not provide anymore than this snippet due to company policy.

Comment: FYI, I resolved the issue by changing the order of the if statements. Now state === INITIALIZING is done the very last, and variable assignment is done right away.  I also added a bit of extra entropy by sleeping randomly between 0-15ms (initialization is not done too often so it's ok).

Comment: "*there are not race conditions for synchronous code*" - yes, but [there are exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734311/1048572). None of which appear in your case though

Answer (score 2):

(V8 developer here.)
I agree that concurrent modification can't happen in JavaScript. The other obvious explanation (that the JS engine incorrectly checked the condition) would be a severe (and pretty obvious!) bug.

But without further information or a repro, it's hard to say anything for sure. For instance, if `this` is an embedder-provided object and `.__state` is an intercepted property, then anything could happen, and it's entirely outside of V8's control. You also mention "sleeping" in the comment: sleeping (and `await`ing) are interruptions of synchronous control flow, so if you have such things in your code, that could also explain why things appear to "magically" change after such a point.

Comment: Sorry, by sleeping I meant to go on a while loop for x amount of time.